# In shapeless, have two lists such that one contains typeclasses of the other

Tags: scala, shapeless

In shapeless I'm trying to write a function such that takes two HLists `l1` and `l2` of arbitrary length which exhibit the following properties:

1. Length of `l1` and `l2` are the same.
2. `l2` contains the exact types of `l1`, wrapped in a constant outer type constructor.

So, if `l1` was

```
1 :: 1.2 :: "hello" :: HNil`
```

`l2` could be

```
Ordering[Int] :: Ordering[Double] :: Ordering[String] :: HNil
```

Using `UnaryTCConstraint` and `LengthAux` lets me constrain the lengths and require a static outer constructor for `l2`, however having them conform has become a problem.

Any ideas on how I could go about it?

Comment: Rather than thinking of it as typeclasses, what you really want is a type `All` (stealing from Agda's nomenclature) that takes a type of kind `* -> *` (the "predicate" over the types; `Ordering` in your case), and an `HList`. I can write it in pure Scala but I'm sure there's a shapeless-friendly way to do it so I'll wait for someone else to show up with that.

Comment: It's not a good solution, but as proof of concept: [link to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1KmuvHJJ).

Comment: @senia: That actually wouldn't be a half bad solution if `Mapped` didn't exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Mapped` provides precisely this constraint without the additional need for `Length`. From [the documentation](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/shapeless-2.0.0-M1/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L51):

> Type class witnessing that the result of wrapping each element of
>   `HList` `L` in type constructor `F` is `Out`.

Here's how it looks in 1.2.4:

```
import shapeless._

def foo[L1 <: HList, L2 <: HList](l1: L1, l2: L2)(implicit
  ev: MappedAux[L1, Ordering, L2]
) = ()

val l1 = 1 :: 1.2 :: "hello" :: HNil
val l2 = Ordering[Int] :: Ordering[Double] :: Ordering[String] :: HNil
val l3 = Ordering[Int] :: Ordering[Double] :: Ordering[Char] :: HNil
```

And then:

```
scala> foo(l1, l2)

scala> foo(l1, l3)
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: ...
```

As expected. For 2.0 just add a `shapeless.ops.hlist._` import and replace `MappedAux` with `Mapped.Aux` and you're ready to go.